# Parsing XML response from AMAZON API in Excel VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, amazon-web-services

I am trying to parse data from Amazon Product Advertising API XML response. I am using DOMDocument in excel vba to load the xml document and parse the resposne. This is how the XML response looks like:

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<OperationRequest>
<HTTPHeaders>...</HTTPHeaders>
<RequestId>fd9f1314-29932-45a0-8fc4-c999276425f4</RequestId>
<Arguments>...</Arguments>
<RequestProcessingTime>0.0265880000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<Items>
<Request>
<IsValid>True</IsValid>
<ItemLookupRequest>
<IdType>ASIN</IdType>
<ItemId>B00CSDILZI</ItemId>
<ItemId>B00BSN8DN4</ItemId>
<ResponseGroup>Offers</ResponseGroup>
<VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
</ItemLookupRequest>
</Request>
<Item>
<ASIN>B00CSDILZI</ASIN>
<OfferSummary>
<LowestNewPrice>
<Amount>26761</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>$267.61</FormattedPrice>
</LowestNewPrice>
<TotalNew>22</TotalNew>
<TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
<TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
<TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
</OfferSummary>
<Offers>
<TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers>
<TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
<MoreOffersUrl>...</MoreOffersUrl>
<Offer>
<OfferAttributes>...</OfferAttributes>
<OfferListing>
<OfferListingId>...</OfferListingId>
<Price>
<Amount>26761</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>$267.61</FormattedPrice>
</Price>
<AmountSaved>
<Amount>23841</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>$238.41</FormattedPrice>
</AmountSaved>
<PercentageSaved>47</PercentageSaved>
<Availability>Usually ships in 1-2 business days</Availability>
<AvailabilityAttributes>
<AvailabilityType>now</AvailabilityType>
<MinimumHours>24</MinimumHours>
<MaximumHours>48</MaximumHours>
</AvailabilityAttributes>
<IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
</OfferListing>
</Offer>
</Offers>
</Item>
<Item>...</Item>
</Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

My ultimate aim is to loop through the entire xml and extract item details like ASIN, FormattedPrice, Lowest price etc to a excel sheet.
But as a first step when I try to access elements from the XML tree, I am not able to do it sucessfuly. I am using Excel 2013 and have referenced to Micrsoft XML 6.0. This is how I tried:

```
Public Function xmlparse()
Dim doc As DOMDocument60
Set doc = New DOMDocument60
doc.Load "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\amazon\offersumm.xml"
Dim Variables As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim variable As IXMLDOMNode
Set Variables = doc.SelectNodes("/ItemLookupResponse/Items")

For Each variable In Variables
    Debug.Print variable.SelectNodes("Item").Item(0).Text

Next
End Function
```

But I am stuck at this point as this prints nothing in the console. Can anyone tell me how to access elements like ASIN, Amount from XML.

Comment: I don't know how you do it in VBA, but it's clear that you need to add the default xmlns namespace to your query to work.

Comment: Thanks for that lead ! I am pretty new to VBA. It would be great if you could elaborate on what you  said, so that I can look up how to get it done in vba.

Comment: Is it like doc .SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces","xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a known issue with how MSXML2 handles default namespaces in XML in XPath queries. If you want to reference a node which is in the default namespace then you have to create a prefix for that namespace and then use that prefix in any XPath query.

So add a namespace definition as follows (I'm using "r" as the prefix):

```
Set doc = New DOMDocument60
doc.Load "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\amazon\offersumm.xml"

doc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:r='http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01'"

Dim Variables As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim variable As IXMLDOMNode
Set Variables = doc.SelectNodes("/r:ItemLookupResponse/r:Items")
```

More details on this issue can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288147)